# How to tell if this old-style fuse is blown?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have recently had my washing machine replaced, and somewhere in the process, the fuse was blown. No big deal, replacement time.

I have replacements. What I don't have is which fuse corresponds to the washing machine group.

I have attached a picture of the fusebox.

[image: My fusebox]

How can I tell which fuse is broken, preferably without trial and error? Some of the other apartments in the same complex route their power through the same fusebox (2 others, to be precise). Landlord has given standing permission for this sort of thing (and has provided the replacements).

**Update**: I managed to figure it out. Thanks for the help. In the end, I remembered I have a (2 decades unused) voltage tester. It turns out that pressing it to the shiny metal bit works to test whether a fuse is good or bad without even having to unscrew them. It was the one on the bottom-left, in the end. But I don't think it's at all visible in this picture.

Comment: Note: If someone knows how to more accurately describe this kind of fuse, I'll happily update the question with those details.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this type of fuse, the top right looks different. The center looks recessed more than the others.

Comment: Fuse blown has a reason ! tell us about the new washing machine, what does the label says

Comment: Through the looking glass you can see witch flues is blown.

Comment: Now, since there are no labels or marking on the outside, you need to unscrew and read the Voltage and the amps of each fuse.

Comment: Checked again, top right doesn't look more depressed from up close. As for the reason for the fuse blowing, I think it has to do with the old washing machine - it had sort of twist-torn the drum, as if one side of it was stuck while turning.

Comment: Attaching a photo to your question of a removed fuse would let us see what the fuse looks like much more completely.

Comment: Now you've solved it, consider a label.  A cheap dymo or brother labeller is effective and saves the next guy time.   Even a word written on masking tape can be informative.

Comment: The specs of the fuse were never the question, though - I have a pile of them next to it, provided by the landlord.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, with this type of fuse, the silver bit in the middle pops up and is less recessed than the others. Not the most visible indicator; I was used to fuses where you had to peer through the glass and see it the contact was gone (and sometimes had left a burnt mark).

Comment: It wasn't noticable, but I found the fuse anyway. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to  buy an inexpensive multi meter, take out one fuse at a time and check for continuity   (base pin to side screw in portion). Now these fuses are not familiar to me so I could be a bit off on my answer. This looks like a non-USA fusebox, it would help to know what country you are in.   Like @ruskes said, the fuse blew for a reason.  Best to sort that out as to why.  Maybe the new washer has a higher current draw than the old one.

Comment: I live in the Netherlands. Every fuse I ever seen (most a lot more modern), are 16A. Most new fuses these days have a simple switch where you can turn them back on, but my current apartment has these old single-use ones.

Comment: If there's a switch where you can turn it back on, it isn't a fuse -- it's a circuit breaker in a fuse body.

Comment: Over here, we still call those circuit breakers the same name as fuses. Because our word is "zekering", which basically "something that ensures something", as in, they ensure there's no too-high amperage. So I'll call that a translation curiosity, and in cases like this I'll add pictures and more words to make sure everyone's thinking of the same thing.